# Mongoose FindOne Query Still Trying to Cast to ObjectID

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

The following code is throwing the following error:

```
await this.GuildModel.findOne({ _id: guildId }).exec((guild) => {
      console.log(guild);
    });
```

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "894673322397302784" (type string) at path "_id" for model "GUILD"
 {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"894673322397302784"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '894673322397302784',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
```

My _id value in my schema and in my database is of type string, and hence I do not want it to be casted to an ObjectID, my schema:

```
const GuildSchema = {
  _id: { type: String },
  prefix: { type: String, default: "!" },
}
```

After doing some research, I realised that I couldn't use findById as it forces it into using an ObjectID, hence why I used findOne. How would I query by my _id which is of type string.

Comment: Why are you implementing your own _id string in the first place?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with doing it like that?

Comment: Yes, it causes the error you are experiencing. You do not need to add _id in your schema. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition (also please do not add unrelated tags to your question)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but which ones are unrelated?

Comment: typescript and nestjs

Comment: Ahh, my apologies - I am working with typescript and nest.js so thought I'd add them to give some context.

Comment: I'd say that there is nothing wrong with using strings as _ids. If that's better for your use case, go for it!
Moreover, findById doesn't (anymore?) force the type of _id to be ObjectId. The only forcing factor is the type definition for `_id` in the schema.
But your schema looks good in that regard. Are you sure you are using this exact object for model creation? I recreated your scenario and it works fine. Maybe you are using some old Mongoose version.

Comment: One more thing. The callback for `.exec()` receives an error object as the first argument, the returned document is second. And in Mongoose v7, `.exec()` doesn't let you pass any callbacks anymore. So I'd advise to stick to the async/await syntax completely (or use promises). Or perhaps did you mean to use `.then()` instead of `.exec()`?